# Javascript or PHP to display data?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm currently using PHP to display data on a page using `echo`, which I thought would be faster than JavaScript.  I'm wondering though if I should be passing data to the page via JSON and have JavaScript show the data instead.  I would think that would give me more flexibility.

**Current code:**

```
 <span class="label">Variable: </span><?php echo $model->variable ?>
```

With all the advancement in JS frameworks, is it more practical to render data via JavaScript these days?

Comment: If your app can run without JS, let it run without JS. It's easy to implement and you don't have to render anything on client. It's better to have support for those, who are disabling it for various purposes.
In the other way, using json may save some bandwith and make better user interactions. 
The best way is to have app which can run as well without JS.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  That was along the lines of what I was thinking.

Comment: @Peky Almost nobody, and I mean nobody, disables Javascript anymore -- you can't use the web without it.

Comment: @GeorgeJempty Yep, but if you want some support for bots / scripts that are using wget to download a page or other needs where you have no option to render it on client, it's needed. It can be done through API, but there is no need for API in most cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise separating your JavaScript and HTML from your PHP and go about structuring your application in a [RESTful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) design.

This gives you a high level of flexibility effectively treating all your server side code as an API which your JavaScript on the front end can make calls to (using AJAX) in order to retrieve data. It will also make your program easier to expand as you can work on server side and client side separately and not accidentally adversely affect other parts of your application.

Comment: +1 for mentionning RESTful design. If you plan to port your service to other programming languages (python, Swift, Java), this is easier to do because you have this nice way to send and receive structured http requests.